# AngularJS: get the order of selection in md-select multiple

Tags: angularjs, md-select

When I select two options in `<md-select>`, I got array of two values. My question is how to get the order of selection?

For example in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/slfan2013/pen/opZXRa), when I select `One` first, and then select `Two`, I got `['1','2']`. Is it possible that I can get `['2','1']` when I select the `Two` first and then `One`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it by implement `ng-change` yourself. 
This's my example in codepen

https://codepen.io/vuph31/pen/dJvGmN?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks. How to display as "Two, One" as well? The value now is ["2","1"] but the user still see "One, Two".